# Bivariate copula for count and continuous variables?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, count-data, continuous-data, copula, association-measure

I'm interested in fit a Copula from my bivariate data with a count variable $Y_{i}$ and a continuous one $X_{i}$.

So, let $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ be the margins for the mentioned variables and $C$ the Copula  such that $\forall x,y $ $H(x,y)=C(F(x),G(y))$, following the Sklar's theorem (**Theorem 2.3.3**, page 18 from [Nelsen (2006)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387286594) ). This theorem suggests that $C$ is unique if both $F$ and $G$ are continuous;

> ... otherwise, $C$ is uniquely determined on $RanF \times RanG$.

So, my main questions, and related, are following:

1. Is this (the Sklar's Theorem) suggesting that if I try to fit the Copula (e.g `fitCopula()` in R ) from my two variables, the results won't be correct because the fitted copula is not unique?
2. Also, could I trust in the Kendall's $\tau$ from these variables?

If answers for 1 and 2 are "yes", will I be wrong if I decide to get the Copula from Kendall's $\tau$?

Thank you so much!